# Android turn on Bluetooth from Service

Tags: android, service, bluetooth

In my application (which in fact should be a stand-alone library) I have to notify the user to turn on the Bluetooth, but all the logic is in a service class. How should I notify the user in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly the structure of your stand-alone library. I advise that you must avoid to use the Activity/Service in your stand-alone library.If you what to use and what to notify the user to turn on Bluetooth, you mean that first you check the status of the Bluetooth, if you find the Bluetooth is off. you what to notify the developer who use your library to develop an app and then the developer notify the user to turn on Bluetooth ?

1.If you what to notify the user directly,you can use Toast or Dialog to remind user to turn on Bluetooth in your service.

2.If you what to notify the developer who use your library, you can use Broadcast,and then the developer can use Toast / Dialog /StartActivityForResult (To popup a system window to remind user to turn on  Bluetooth).

If you are develop apps related to Bluetooth.You must pay attention that you must listen the status of Bluetooth.Once Bluetooth status changed, you must notify user.